# I having a error with data structures

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am having  a error from the compiler telling me that "student" "does not refer to a value" it was to my understanding student.test  refers to a value and that value has already be initialized to  the variable. I need help

```
int main() {
ifstream dataIn;
ofstream dataOut;


struct student{
    string  lastName=" ";
    string firstName=" ";
    int test1=0;
    int test2=0;
    int test3=0;
    int test4=0;
    int test5=0;
   };
char grade=' ';
int total=0;
int average =0;
average=averageScore(student.test1, student.test2, student.test3,  student.test4,student.test5,student.average, student.total);
```

Comment: `student.test1` is like saying `string.length()` or `ifstream << "foo";`

Comment: your student struct does not have any data members for "average" and "total", but you are trying to use those as arguments for calling the averageScore function.
I guess, you have closed the struct to early with the "};" above "char grade=' ';".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `struct student` is a type definition and not a variable declaration.

Therefore, in order to access the fields you should declare a variable of this type, and use the variable and not the class i.e.:

```
student st;
char grade=' ';
int total=0;
int average =0;
average=averageScore(st.test1, st.test2, st.test3,  st.test4,st.test5,st.average, st.total);
```

(And also, as [Mr. Yellow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4689198/mr-yellow) mentioned the average field is not defined for `struct student`)